# How to check which person clone my project in github

Tags: github

I have my projects on **github**, and they're *public*. How would I know that my projects have been cloned, and by whom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now way of telling who have cloned your project.

But, Github provides basic statistics about visitors and clones in 'Graphs' option on your repository. Here is a [link](https://github.com/blog/1873-clone-graphs).

Also you can see who has forked your project:
A number showed on top right corner on your repo present on [Github](http://www.github.com).
Go to Graphs->Members to check out who forked your repo.

Hope this helps.